# Custome Filterlist in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a search bar and using these two libraries. I have filter list on the search bar

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and when it gives me a simple filter list but I want some changes in the design of that filter list. Right now it is like this
[image: Simple Filter List]

But I want my search filter like this

[image: Desired output]

I tried a lot but I failed. This is code what i tried for

```
$('.ui-front').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'li', function(e) {
    var arjuna=e.target.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
    e.target.removeChild(e.target.childNodes[0]);

    $('.ui-front').off('DOMNodeInserted');


    $(e.target).append(
            '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">' +
            '<div class="row">'+
            '<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="justify-content: center;display: flex;">' +
            '<img src="https://images.hugoboss.com/is/image/boss/hbeu50325887_399_100?$re_fullPageZoom$&amp;qlt=85&amp;extendN=0.05%2C0.05%2C0.05%2C0.05&amp;wid=461&amp;hei=698" alt="Product Picture" style="height: auto;width: 50px;">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">' +
            '<h4 style="color: blue;padding: 6px;font-size: 14.5px;">'+arjuna+'</h4>' +
            '<h5 style="color: black;font-size: 14px;padding-left: 6px;">Figura infantil Ben10 (Cannotbolt), 4X5In (10x13cm)</h5>'+
            '<h6 style="float: left;color: black;padding: 6px;font-size: 13px;"><del>$ 77.00</del></h6>'+
            '<h6 style="font-size: 13px;float: left;margin-left: 10px;color: black;padding: 6px;">$ 75.00</h6>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<hr style="margin-top:7px;margin-bottom:7px">'
);
});
```

In this code, I am removing the list items of the unordered list and insert my HTML code but due to `DOMNodeInserted` it becomes an infinite loop. Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Comment: First thing first, are you using JqueryAutocomplete to implement the search? If that is the case then its quite simple to do that.

Comment: can u tell me how?

Comment: In the Jquery Autocomplete, After the search completes you get the event, In which you can define your custom HTML. Go to this link https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data and click view source link in the explanation. you will see .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem This is where you can define your custom HTML